# How to use variables in sed

Tags: bash, sed, bash-script

I want to print out the lines of a file between two indices in a Bash script. I have the file name and indices as variables

I tried doing this

```
sed -n "$2,$3p" $1

sed: -e expression #1, char 4: invalid usage of line address 0
```

but I got an error. How do I do this?

Comment: What are $2 and $3's values? What is the error message?

Comment: @manatwork $2 and $3 are the second and third input arguments.

Comment: “0,addr2 (…) This works only when addr2 is a regular expression.” – man sed. From the error message we found out $2 is 0. So, what is $3's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the main issue here is that there is no such thing as line 0. `sed` starts counting lines from 1. Presumably, assuming the rest of your script is OK, this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed -n "$2,$3p" "$1"
```

I tried the script above on this file:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
$ ./foo.sh file 3 5
line 3
line 4
line 5
$ ./foo.sh file 0 5
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: invalid usage of line address 0
$ ./foo.sh file 1 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

From `man sed` (thanks @manatwork):

> 0,addr2
>
> Start  out  in  "matched  first  address"  state, until addr2 is
>   found.  This is similar to 1,addr2, except that if addr2 matches
>   the very first line of input the 0,addr2 form will be at the end
>   of its range, whereas the 1,addr2 form  will  still  be  at  the
>   beginning of its range.  **This works only when addr2 is a regular
>   expression.**

So, this should work as well:

```
$ a.sh file 0 "/line 3/"
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

If you are using normal named variables, it will fail because your shell has no way of knowing where the variable's name ends and the `sed` commands begin. For example:

```
foo=1; sed -n "$foop"
```

will print nothing since the shell will treat `$foop` as the variable name. To get around that, use curly braces:

```
$ foo=1; sed -n "${foo}p" file
line 1
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine using the nth variable format. However if I use stored variables like `$a`, it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you could add an example for the address 0 case I quoted in my comment: `./foo.sh file 0 /5/`.

Comment: @manatwork I already fixed that, I guess it should have worked if i didn't have zero in the input.

Comment: @manatwork I can't get it to work with any variation of `sed -n '0,foo'`. If you know how this works, feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: “foo” is not valid regular expression. Should be “/foo/”: `sed -n '0,/foo/'`.

Comment: @manatwork ah, that's what they mean by regex, they mean match operator. Grrr... I tried with `li.*ne` which is a perfectly valid regex and it still failed. Perfect, thanks updating answer now.

Comment: Another thing you could add is the brace-enclosed variable name, to answer [user2798694' comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107301/how-to-use-variables-in-sed#comment164784_107306): `sed -n "$from,${to}p" "$file"`.

Comment: @manatwork good point, answer edited.

Comment: Just nitpicking: not `sed`, but `bash` has no way of knowing where the variable's name ends.